# CORBA JacORB idlj CosNotification/EventType is an undeclared type?

Tags: java, corba, idl, jacorb

I have an idl file which I am trying to generate Java bindings using the IDL-to-Java Compiler `idlj` and using the JacORB omg idl files. Below is the idl file I am trying to compile where I am getting the error. What is causing the error?

> /jacorb-3.8/idl/omg//CosNotifyComm.idl (line 13):  CosNotification/EventType is an undeclared type.
>     exception InvalidEventType { CosNotification::EventType type; };
>                                                             ^
>   /jacorb-3.8/idl/omg//orb.idl (line 9):  Expected one of `typedef' >`struct' `union'`enum' `const'`exception' `interface'`valuetype' >`module'; encountered`'.
>   typeprefix CORBA "omg.org">

and below is the idl file I am trying to compile with the following command
`idlj -fall -i "/jacorb-3.8/idl/omg/" NotificationIRPSystem.idl`

[NotificatoinIRPSystem.idl](https://pastebin.com/aMGWzijf)

Comment: From which java version is this 'idlj' command from? Can you check with either 'which' (for UNIX) or 'where (for Windows) command?

Comment: Hi Iwan, java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem with Idlj. I could compile with jacORB/bin/ idl as follows.
Link: http://www.jacorb.org/download.html

```
./idl -I. NotificationIRPSystem.idl
```

Comment: Hi egcodes, tried that jacorb idl and it worked. By the way, I like to know what's the `-I.` option means? I tried checking the `idl -help` but it was not there. Thanks!

Comment: -I: IncludePath. For example, -I folderName